# Is it possible to have GoDaddy host my domain name but use AWS to host my website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web

I'm a little confused on what Aws is instructing me to do.  They are telling me to transfer the name to Route 53 first which cost 12 bucks.  Is there a way to not use Route 53 and still host my website using Aws?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Perhaps you should try posting the exact issue you are encountering and we can tell you what your GoDaddy DNS settings should be.

Comment: Yes; just make a CNAME or A record that points to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

you can have your domain at any registrar and have your DNS zone hosted anywhere. Just modify DNS records to point to your AWS resources like ELB, EC2 or S3.

Amazon doesn't force you to use Route53.

Answer (score 0):

AWS is boss, if you are trying to capitalize on the ACM and get a free SSL you do need to use Route53 to make it happen. Try to test a PTR - Pointer record to your ip address within the DNS to make everything working
Third Party Domain Registrar/DNS

1. Create a hosted zone through Route53 and erase all DNS/Nameservers
   from your domain.
2. Add the four nameservers to your domain
   registrar's DNS should have a mix of .org .com .net and .co.uk or
   something similar. All four need to be insterted.
3. After creating your instance and having your domain pointed to it you will
   need point the ip address to Route 53 with an A record. Keep it that
   way for now
4. Generate a certificate with ACM as described above
   Create an ELB as described above as well Now with the DNS first make
   a *.domain.com A record to point to your dualstack.
5. Then delete the original A record that pointed to your ip address
6. Next make sure you point the A record now to your
   dualstack.loadbalancer for your regular domain.com
7. Next, here was the crucial part for me, make a PTR - Pointer record
   to your ip address with domain.com as the name
8. Viola free certificate will work with Wordpress

Oh, and if your design looks funky or any issues getting the green bar then it's something embeded so start with this plugin, make sure "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO (e.g. load balancer, reverse proxy, NginX)" is enabled and then move on from there with your typical ssl auditing. https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/11

A lot of cool info for AWS + Wordpress via bitnami and more details on the SSL here: https://community.bitnami.com/t/connecting-amazon-ssl-via-load-balancer-to-bitnami-aws-marketplace-instance/41460/29

Let me know if you have trouble getting started on actually launching the instance and getting wordpress up first. The domain pointing and ssl is one of the last steps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is pretty common.

In Route53, create a new zone for your domain.  When you do this, you'll get the NS and SOA records created by default. There will be 4 NS entries.  Add any other records you need.

Then, when you're ready to switcy, go to the godaddy DNS settings, and change the NS and SOA records to the values in the Route53 zone.  By default, I think godaddy only shows 2 NS records, but you can add all 4.